# How to correlate graph properties with vertex attributes?

Tags: correlation, graph-theory

I have a directed graph, **S**, where each vertex stores several integers of attributes. I think it might be called a ["attribute relational graph"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688389/what-are-attribute-relational-graphs) or just an old fashioned "attributed graph". The networkx Python package allows any attributes to be added to each vertex, but I can't figure out how to pair these attributes with features of the graph.

Let's say I have the following vertices representing moments in time:

- **S1**, where Alice has \$1, Bob has \$2, and Cindy has \$5.
- **S2**, where Alice has \$0, Bob has \$3, and Cindy has \$5.
- **S3**, where Alice has \$0, Bob has \$0, and Cindy has \$8.

Edges between the vertices imply a temporal connection between the moments in time, for example, before and after a transaction between Alice, Bob, and Cindy. Additionally, vertex weight and edge weight are the frequency of that state or transaction occurring over a long period of sampling at discrete time intervals.

My question is, how can I compute correlations between those numeric attributes and the graph topology?

The only place I can think to start would be to cluster **S**, using the graph topology, and analyze the change of attributes between vertices within each cluster. For that you could define a similarity metric like the difference between the edge connecting each pair of vertices and check if this is correlated within a cluster.

Are there any standard algorithms for this type of analysis or am I looking at all custom code?

Other things I'd also be interested in computing,

- A greedy "loss-only" path for Alice, what is the shortest number of transactions to make her broke from any given point.
- The number of occurrences in the graph where Bob acts an an intermediate party to Alice and Cindy.

Comment: I believe this is a topic being addressed in [current research](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.6568)